# Calculating the expectation value of a spin operator in a uniform magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, polarization

I'm trying

[image: Tripos question]

Usually for these types of questions, I'm used to the field being in a specific direction.
For example, if the field was in the $z$ direction, I could find this solution by checking

$|< Sz, Q >|^2$ where $Q$ is the state vector at time $t$.

Does anyone know how to begin the approach to this case where the field isn't in some specific direction?

Comment: Three methods. Method (1): pick $z$ direction along $B$, then consider how your results can be expressed in vector notation. Method (2): write ${\bf n} \cdot {\bf \sigma} = n_x \sigma_z + n_y \sigma+y + n_z \sigma_z$ and take it from there. Method (3) (more fancy) stick to vector notation throughout.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Calculate $\textbf{n} \cdot \textbf{S}$, then use your result to find the eigenspinors and their associated eigenvalues of your Hamiltonian.   Remember that $x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$, $y = r\sin\theta\sin\phi$, and $z = \cos\theta$. Then you can write down the general state $|{\chi(t)}\rangle$, and solve the TDSE. Can you take it from here?